# MongoDB Atlas: High number of connections alert

Tags: mongodb, connection-pooling, mongodb-atlas

I have a small MongoDB Atlas cluster with a limit of 100 connections. The dashboard is showing me an alert for the number of connections but I only have a couple of connected clients.

What is the reason for the high number of connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that your client applications are sharing the same driver client instance. Make it a singleton and reuse it, don't instantiate new clients on every request.

Next, configure the max connection pool size. The max connection count on an M2 cluster is 100 and the [default for the connection pool size is 100](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.maxPoolSize).

You can override the value in code or directly in the connection string using the following syntax

```
mongodb+srv://user:password@...?&retryWrites=true&w=majority&maxPoolSize=10
```